# What will be fragment behavior when came from background. Considering fragment is in stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Navigation panel activity. With 5 fragments (Will name it as Fragment1, Fragment2, ...) in menu sections.

Now by Default, activity will display Fragment1.

If user navigate to Fragmentxtz from Fragment1. We will add the fragment on top of Fragment1.

Now user goes to background by pressing home button and open the app from tasks.

Now i know Fragmentxtz onStart will be called. But i see that Fragment1 onStart is also called.

Is this expected behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on Android Developers, your fragment will be called at onViewCreated().

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Creating

The View has to be updated in case you changed the system language or something like that.

Comment: Yes, I know the flow. But my question is , if the fragment is in back stack, that means there is another fragment which is top of this fragment. In that case, if you go background and foreground, then the fragment which is in back stack also calls its onStart() . I understand that the fragment which has come to foreground will call its life cycle events  but not the one which is in backstack.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a bit more context to what might be happening here.

If both of your fragments are added e.g. via [FragmentTransaction.add()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#add(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) both of them will have `onCreateView()` called when the layout is restored for the user as Robert pointed out. From the system's point of view all of those fragments are relevant to the user and would be shown simultaneously.

If on the other hand you add fragments via [FragmentTransaction.replace()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#replace(int,%20androidx.fragment.app.Fragment)) only the topmost fragment on the back stack will receive the `onCreateView()` call. This can also be achieved by doing an `add` and `remove` of the old fragment. If you make this transaction reversible by the back stack after pressing the back button your previous fragment would receive the appropriate lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: If you have 10 fragment added in stack "FragmentTransaction.add()"  and user goes background and foreground. All 10 fragment onCreateView() is called ? Just wondering does it work like this?

Comment: @YogeshByndoor Yes, because you can show multiple Fragments side by side in one Activity and some Fragments might not have UI at all and just do some background work while others are displayed. So you have to explicitly tell the framework to remove unused Fragments.

Comment: Thanks, I am convinced.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Consider upvoting and marking solutions that helped you solve your problem. This will help others find relevant answers and increase the reputation of the members that helped you.